# How to set up CORS with Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, cors, drupal-8

I am setting up a view with views, with display being rest JSON, how can I set up the `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)` for it.

I suppose the solution is to modify the default.services.yml, which is indicated by https://www.drupal.org/node/2715637 and I did already.

But I still can not request the JSON resource from a different host. Does somebody know how to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: The question is....once you updated the `yml` file, did you restart the apache service?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a blog about this, [checkit](https://josuevalrob.com/setup-drupal-for-web-services)

Find: `.../sites/default/default.services.yml`

Make a copy and rename the copy to:

```
.../sites/default/services.yml
```

Find this part of the code: cors.config: enabled: false

and replace with the following - cors.config: enabled: true

Add the sites that you want to share, for example:

```
cors.config:
    enabled: true
    # Specify allowed headers, like 'x-allowed-header'.
    allowedHeaders: ['*']
    # Specify allowed request methods, specify ['*'] to allow all possible ones.
    allowedMethods: ['*']
    # Configure requests allowed from specific origins.
    allowedOrigins: ['http://localhost:4200']
    # Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.
    exposedHeaders: false
    # Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age header.
    maxAge: false
    # Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
    supportsCredentials: false
```

Clear the cache.